# Store Many Rows In Sql Server Issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Working on My Program that Works With SQL Server.

for Store Data in Database Table, Which of the below approaches is correct?

1. Store Many Rows Just in One Table (10 Million Record)
2. Store Fewer Rows in Several Table (500000 Record) (exp: for each Year Create One Table)

Comment: use 1. - 10 Million rows isn't considered "many" nowadays.

Comment: many table's rows Causes do increase time for 'select' query?

Comment: It depends on how many rows you get with the `select`. The more you select the longer it takes. But why would you always select all rows?

Comment: actually i want to know that how many time difference for sql search between 10 million record with 5000 record? (Same 'select' Query)? this difference time is big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends! 
What are you going to do with the data? If you are querying this data a lot of times it could be a better solution to split the data in (for example) year tables. That way you would have a better performance since you have to query smaller tables.
But on the other side. With a bigger table and with good query's you might not even see a performance issue. If you only need to store this data it would be better to just use 1 table.

BTW For loading this data into the database you could use BCP (bulkcopy), which is a fast way of inserting a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how often you access data.If you are not using the old records, then you can archive those records. Splitting up of tables is not desirable as it may confuse you while fetching data.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to store all the data in a single table, but implement a table partition on the older data. Partioning the data will increase query performance.

Here are some references:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1914/sql-server-database-partitioning-myths-and-truths/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/

Please note that this table partioning functionality is only available in Enterprise Edition.